# Why avoid Method.invoke?

Tags: java, java-security

In [guideline 9-11 / ACCESS-11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html#9-11)

> Be aware `java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke` is ignored for checking the
> immediate caller

of the [Secure Coding Guidelines for Java SE](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/seccodeguide.html), it is stated that the `Method.invoke` implementation is ignored when determining the immediate caller, because otherwise the action would be performed with all permissions. So far that's clear to me, but then it is stated:

> Therefore, avoid `Method.invoke`

I understand it is good that the `Method.invoke` implementation is ignored when determining the immediate caller, but why it should be avoided? What would be the reason to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

There is an inherent risk when using reflection for invoking methods ( like in Java or C#). Quoting from the OWASP vulnerability description page for [Unsafe use of reflection](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Unsafe_use_of_Reflection)

> If an attacker can supply values that the application then uses to
> determine which class to instantiate or which method to invoke, the
> potential exists for the attacker to create control flow paths through
> the application that were not intended by the application developers.

Comment: @Philippe - thanks for pointing about the link. I have corrected now !